# Kotlin-Android First App Unresolved Reference TextView with Button

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I'm new to android and kotlin development and I am having trouble with my first application.

I am looking to edit my TextView on button click but the compiler is complaining about an unresolved reference.

Here is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/click_me"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onTap"
        android:text="Click me"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Not clicked..."
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/click_me"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/click_me" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is my MainActivity.kt file

```
package com.example.helloworld

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    //Method will be called on button click
    fun onTap(view: View) {
            textView.text = "Clicked"
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Kotlin Android Extensions is deprecated and should no longer be used. Read the documentation on View Binding.

Answer (score 2):

you should define the textview as variable and then you could change it

val textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_id)

textView.setText("string").toString()

val textViewValue = textView.text

Answer (score 2):

As other user already commented, you should use view binding.

On your app Gradle script.

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Then on your MainActivity

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.yourButtonID.setOnClickListener {buttonTtapped()}
    }

    fun buttonTtapped() {
            binding.yourTextViewID.text = "Clicked"
     } 
}
```

Something like this

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply this in your build.gradle file

```
plugins {
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'}
```

and press sync now
then back to your MainActivity it will suggest u to import that view

Comment: synthetic imports are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin has a feature **Say goodbye to findViewById** refered for **Kotlin Android Extensions**. You need to import the `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*` so that you directly use the ID name of the view directly.

To get this work you need to add this plugin in the module-level `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

**Another approach by findViewById**

```
class SampleActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun onTap(view: View){
        val myTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        myTextView.text = "absc"
    }

}
```

Comment: synthetic imports are deprecated